# isomorphism of subsets and normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose $G$ is the direct product of $H$ and $B$, $H \times B$, with $A$ a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $A$ is a subset of $B$. Prove that $G/A$ is isomorphic to $ H \times (B/A)$

Comment: When you say that $A$ is a subset of $B$, do you mean that $A\subseteq \{1_H\}\oplus B$? Also, you should show at least show your thoughts on the question, rather than just copying the question down word for word.

Comment: Yes , it means the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll outline the proof, and you can fill in the steps. The elements of $G/A'$ have the form $(h,b)+A'$ where $h\in H, b\in B$, and the elements of $H\oplus (B/A)$ have the form $(h,b+A)$, where $h\in H,b\in B$. (I'm using $A'$ to mean $A$ as a subgroup of $G$, and $A$ to be the subgroup of $B$.) You want an isomorphism $f:G/A'\to H\oplus (B/A)$, that is a structure preserving bijection. The simplest function we can consider is $f((h,b)+A')=(h,b+A)$, so let's try that.

Before you can actually show that this is an isomorphism, you have to verify that it's a function. Specifically, you need to show that $f$ is well-defined on the cosets of $A'$. That is, you need to show that if $(h_1,b_1)+A'=(h_2,b_2)+A'$, then $(h_1,b_1+A)=(h_2,b_2+A)$. To do this, you should use the fact that if $x$ and $y$ are in the same coset of $N$ for a normal subgroup $N$, then $x-y\in N$. Since $A'$ has form $\{1_H\}\oplus A$, then $(h_1,b_1)-(h_2,b_2)=(h_1-h_2,b_1-b_2)=(1_H,a)$ for some $a\in A$. That should allow you to show that $(h_1,b_1+A)=(h_2,b_2+A)$.

Proving that $f$ is a structure preserving bijection should just come naturally from the definition of those things.